# Bean Portlet in Liferay 7.2 DXP

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-dxp

Has any one created a Bean Portlet in Liferay DXP ?

I followed up https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028708772-Creating-a-Bean-Portlet and executed the command

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.liferay -DarchetypeArtifactId=com.liferay.project.templates.cdi.bean.portlet -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0 -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=com.mycompany.demo.bean.portlet
```

But getting following Error.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.liferay:com.liferay.project.templates.cdi.bean.portlet:1.0.0) -> [Help 1]

Seems template is missing !

Thanks & Regards,

Parth Ghiya

Answer (score 0):

We get the same error - I believe that the reason is that the related development ticket is still in the "In Review" Status:
https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-83990

You can create a Jira account and vote on this ticket to show the developers that many people are interested in this feature.

Best Regards,
Peter